# Django Admin :: Adding WYSIWYG editors for multiple text area

Tags: javascript, django, dojo, django-admin, tinymce

I tried to use both tinyMCE and dojo's editor in Django's admin without success. The second textarea in a page (of inline items) freaks out and can't receive focus.

I've used [tutorials from django's site](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/AddWYSIWYGEditor).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have a look at [django-tinymce](https://github.com/aljosa/django-tinymce). It has an HTMLField that you can use as a replacement TextField with TinyMCE integration. I've used it on several projects.